# Calling DB2 Stored Procedure in nodejs with User Defined Type array as parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, db2, db2-luw

Im trying to call a stored procedure with a parameter anchored to a user defined type array. I'm using node-ibm_db npm module. I tried following the samples found in the node_modules/ibm_db/test/test-array-insert.js.

I came up with my sample test program following the conecepts found in the ibm_db test programs

```
    var common = require("./common")
  , ibmdb = require("../")
  , schema = common.connectionObject.CURRENTSCHEMA
  , insertCount = 0;
  ;

ibmdb.debug(true);
ibmdb.open(common.connectionString, function(err, conn) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  conn.querySync("create table arrtab (c1 INTEGER, c2 INTEGER, c3 char(1), c4 varchar(10))");
  conn.querySync("CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SAMPLE_TYPE AS ROW ( C1 INTEGER, C2 INTEGER, C3 char(1), C4 VARCHAR(10))");
  conn.querySync("CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SAMPLE_ARR AS SAMPLE_TYPE ARRAY[100]");
 
  err = conn.querySync("CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_TYPE ( IN P_ARRAY SAMPLE_ARR) BEGIN INSERT INTO ARRTAB (C1,C2,C3,C4) SELECT C1,C2,C3,C4 FROM UNNEST(P_ARRAY) AS (C1,C2, C3, C4); END")
  if(err.length) { console.log(err); return; }

  var paramC1 = {ParamType:"ARRAY", DataType:1, Data:[0,1,2]}
  var paramC2 = {ParamType:"ARRAY", DataType:1, Data:[19,20,18]}
  var paramC3 = {ParamType:"ARRAY", DataType:1, Data:['Y','N','Y']}
  var paramC4 = {ParamType:"ARRAY", DataType:"VARCHAR", Data:['BMWX','TESL','TOYO'], Length:4} 
  var final = {ParamType:"ARRAY", DataType:1, Data: [paramC1,paramC2,paramC3,paramC4]}


  conn.querySync("insert into arrtab values (9, 4, 'Y', 'rock')");
  if(err.length) { console.log(err); return; }

  var data = conn.querySync("select * from arrtab");
  console.log("\nSelected data for table ARRTAB =\n", data);

 var queryOptions = { sql: "call test_type(?)",
                      params: [final],
                      ArraySize:3}
//   var queryOptions = {sql: "insert into arrtab values (?,?,?,?)",
//                       params: [paramC1, paramC2, paramC3, paramC4],
//                       ArraySize: 3}
  err = conn.querySync(queryOptions);
  console.log(err)

  var data = conn.querySync("select * from arrtab");
  console.log("\nSelected data for table ARRTAB =\n", data);
  conn.querySync("drop table arrtab");

});
```

Basically, the use case is i will be passing a set of table data to the stored procedure for saving. To do this I created a udt row and a udt array based on the udt row. It seems ibm_db is unable to accept a complex array paramter.

```
C:\Users\r\Documents\Github\test>node node_modules\ibm_db\test\test-array-sp2.js    
node-ibm_db logs enabled.
1.11 ::  odbc.js:querySync() =>  create table arrtab (c1 INTEGER, c2 INTEGER, c3 char(1), c4 varchar(10))
1.18 ::  odbc.js:querySync() =>  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SAMPLE_TYPE AS ROW ( C1 INTEGER, C2 INTEGER, C3 char(1), C4 VARCHAR(10))1.239 ::  odbc.js:querySync() =>  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SAMPLE_ARR AS SAMPLE_TYPE ARRAY[100]
1.25 ::  odbc.js:querySync() =>  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_TYPE ( IN P_ARRAY SAMPLE_ARR) BEGIN INSERT INTO ARRTAB (C1,C2,C3,C4) SELECT C1,C2,C3,C4 FROM UNNEST(P_ARRAY) AS (C1,C2, C3, C4); END
1.271 ::  odbc.js:querySync() =>  insert into arrtab values (9, 4, 'Y', 'rock')
1.287 ::  odbc.js:querySync() =>  select * from arrtab

Selected data for table ARRTAB =
 [ { C1: 9, C2: 4, C3: 'Y', C4: 'rock' } ]
1.316 ::  odbc.js:querySync() =>  call test_type(?)
Error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0301N  The value of input variable, expression or parameter number "1" cannot be used because of its data type.  SQLSTATE=07006

    at Database.querySync (C:\Users\r\Documents\Github\test\node_modules\ibm_db\lib\odbc.js:793:30)
    at C:\Users\r\Documents\Github\test\node_modules\ibm_db\test\test-array-sp2.js:40:14
    at C:\Users\r\Documents\Github\test\node_modules\ibm_db\lib\odbc.js:111:11
    at C:\Users\r\Documents\Github\test\node_modules\ibm_db\lib\odbc.js:333:11 {
  error: '[node-ibm_db] Error in ODBCConnection::QuerySync while executing query.',
  sqlcode: -301,
  state: '07006'
}
1.362 ::  odbc.js:querySync() =>  select * from arrtab

Selected data for table ARRTAB =
 [ { C1: 9, C2: 4, C3: 'Y', C4: 'rock' } ]
1.367 ::  odbc.js:querySync() =>  drop table arrtab
```

Does anyone know if it is even possible to do this? I think this is a common use case, and we used to handle this easily when we were still using mybatis and java. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error says the input data type is incompatible. Why is array size 3 and the array has four entries?

Comment: Ok, a little bit of context. I shouldve started with this. There was an issue raised in the ibm_db github page. A new feature was introduced that would enable bulk inserts thru the use of arrays. But the samples they provided all featured a column-wise binding, meaning if you have a table with 2 columns, you are required to have 2 separate arrays that you would bind to the parameter marker. I raised a question if its possible have a table type as a parameter, which is doable via sql as illustrated in my sample stored procedure. In short, the array size 3 is required for the length of array

Comment: I am guessing that I am looking for row-wise binding which is a feature of odbc. Unless my understanding of parameter binding is totally wrong. https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/t0007269.html

Comment: The stored-procedure requires an input-parameter but you supply no parameter, which is a separate error unrelated to `node-ibm_db` capabilities. Either provide an empty array, or a populated array.  For `node-ibm_db` it may be better to progress this via github instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: The parameter is provided via the queryOptions object that is passed to querySync api.  Refer to the object "final" as parameter of the queryOption. Actually I was hoping someone have already stumbled upon my similar use case, and i posted it here since this site has a wider reach versus the project's github page. The project mainteners are not really responsive, I only see one guy answering all the questions, and it seems not everything is being answered, especially for followup questions.

Comment: Hi, were u able to find a solution for this problem? @Tiesto

Comment: @Akshay. We were not able to solve this problem since i think the package itself has no support for it. If you find a solution, would appreciate you sharing it with me.